# Integration test for user saving does not work

Tags: spring-boot, h2, spring-test

I have a Spring Boot application. Now I try to cover my user service with integration test. My method which check what user has added in database does not work. I added h2 database in my pom.xml file and create test properties for this DB. When When I try to run the test the following error occurs

**Error**

[Error is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zD5DO.png)

**Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-     4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>by.yankavets</groupId>
    <artifactId>TypingTrainer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>TypingTrainer</name>
    <description>TypingTrainer</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.24.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Test Class**

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {UserServiceImpl.class})
@TestPropertySource("/application-test.properties")
public class UserServiceImplTest {

    private static final Long TEST_ID = 123L;
    public static final User TEST_USER;
    public static final String TEST_USER_NAME = "Ivan";

    public static final String TEST_USER_EMAIL = "test@email.com";

    public static final String TEST_PASSWORD = "1234";

    public static final Role TEST_USER_ROLE;

    public static final Set<Role> TEST_ROLES;
    private static final List<User> TEST_USER_LIST;

    private List<User> userList;

    static {
        TEST_USER_LIST = new ArrayList<>();
        TEST_USER_ROLE = Role.builder()
                .name("ROLE_USER")
                .build();
        TEST_ROLES = Set.of(TEST_USER_ROLE);
        TEST_USER = User.builder()
                .id(TEST_ID)
                .name(TEST_USER_NAME)
                .email(TEST_USER_EMAIL)
                .password(TEST_PASSWORD)
                .roles(TEST_ROLES)
                .build();
        TEST_USER_LIST.add(TEST_USER);
    }
    @MockBean
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Add user in database test")
    void addUserInDatabaseTest() {
        userService.save(TEST_USER);
        Optional<User> savedUser = userRepository.findByEmail(TEST_USER.getEmail());
        assertThat(savedUser).isPresent();
        assertThat(savedUser).isEqualTo(TEST_USER);
    }
```

**Properties file**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:jpa_jbd
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

I tried to move properties file, changed username and pasword, delete h2 dependencies, changed scope, wrote Transactional annotation.

Comment: what are your expectations from using `@MockBean`? You told `spring` to mock `UserRepository` and place it into application context. Mocking means that mocked service by default do nothing on void methods and returns "reasonable defaults" (nulls and empty optionals) for other methods. Now you may check that `userService` actually calls `userRepository` via `verify(userRepository, times(1)).save();` or setup behaviour of `userRepository` via `when/thenXXX`.

Comment: Thanks. `@MockBean` I use for other tests (ex. findAllUser). If I use verify() method test works. Is there way to check that we have added this user (for example by email)